# Android reduce screen brightness below the normal(default) level

Tags: java, android

I would like to do a App with some function same as Screen Filter,which is can control the screen brightness and reduce the brightness level below that default level (some website call it "negative brightness").
I have try some method to do it,but it just can reduce until the default min brightness.

```
    android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, screen_brightness);
```

which screen_brightness just can only between 0 and 255.

Is it exist some method or function can reduce screen brightness below minimum ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use a darker color to simulate a reduced brightness?
For example, rgb(255,255,255) is white, but you can use rgb(128,128,128) to show a gray color, which also simulates a full-white but with half brightness.

So an option is multiply all colors on your screen by a brightness adjust factor. This method can be used in some e-book reading App.